# d3 Area graph fill issue

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to display a time based d3 area graph. There is a very strange 'tail' at the start of thie graph and I'm not sure what is causing the issue.

Here is the JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qxkRJ/

I convert the date to the correct format but am wondering if the issue arises because of the data isn't ordered by the datetime value.

```
data.forEach(function (d) {
            var newDate = new Date(d.daterun/1000000);
            d.daterun = newDate;
            d.intvalue = +d.intvalue;
        });
```

Comment: Well, does it look ok when sorted? http://jsfiddle.net/qxkRJ/1/

Comment: Ok, I'll add this as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is sort the data:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) { return a.daterun - b.daterun; });
```

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qxkRJ/1/).

Comment: I had a perfectly ordered json input and still at some point the order was getting changed automatically leading the graph to be distorted. I then sorted the data anyway and the graph started showing up correctly. Thanks!